# XPath find_elements_by_xpath() returns empty list, but XPath helper extension shows results

Tags: xpath, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.7

I'm having trouble with getting the `href` attribute article links from the page with `XPath`.

So, this is the result from the query using the Chrome extension XPath Helper on https://www.ethics.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/dearcolleagueletters?page=1:

```
//table[@class="table recordList"]//@href
```

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from threading import Thread

url_xpath = '//table[@class="table recordList"]//@href'
url = 'https://www.ethics.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/dearcolleagueletters?page=1'
            
options = Options()
options.headless = True
# change filepath of chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\chromedriver')
    
try:
    driver.get(url)
    print("got url") #<- reaches here
    url_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(url_xpath)
    print("url_elements", url_elements) # <- doesn't reach here
    for url_elements in url_elements:
        article_url = url_elements.get_attribute('href')
        print("article url", article_url)
except:  
   pass
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `xpath` expression used.
Because you're using `//@href` at the end, you're getting an error because the returned results are not actually of type `element` but an `attribute`:

```
Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//table[@class="table recordList"]//@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

Besides this, you're also getting the attachments icon `href` which may or may not be in your requirements.

To get only the article links you can use this `xpath` expression:

```
//table[@class="table recordList"]//a[@class=\'ContentGrid\']
```

If you need both, the article URL and attachments URL you can use this:

```
//table[@class="table recordList"]//a[@class='ContentGrid' or @title='View Files']
```